# wierd poblem with shaders on minecraft without report

Tags: minecraft

When ever I run `Minecraft Shaders` it brings me back to the launcher (after going into a world/server)without a crash report! I have to **uninstall the mod** to play Minecraft even though I am using the correct version. This worked for my friend (who uses Windows 8).
How can i fix this?

Comment: Issues with Minecraft mods are not necessarily on-topic for this site, as it's not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: @ThomasW. I don't see why mods of [already] third-party software makes it any more or less on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

The shaders are likely utilising OpenGL/GLSL features that your graphics card and its driver have not yet implemented. Even if hardware can do something, it needs the software there to interpret it and these drivers sometimes lag behind their Windows counterparts.

This is *most* true on the Intel and other open source graphics drivers. They are currently hovering around OpenGL 3.1 while the current proprietary Nvidia and AMD drivers will give you 4.4.

So if...

- You're on the open source Nvidia driver, upgrade to their proprietary driver.
- You're on open-source AMD, consider installing their proprietary driver (some people seem to struggle with it though so be cautious).
- You're on Intel, you have little choice. Hardware upgrade or wait it out.